# how can i set style of imageview runtime in android

Tags: android, view

i can set a style like this

```
ImageView
android:id="@+id/blah"
style="@style/mystyle"
/>
```

But Is there a way to set a style for a View at runtime? Like

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(...);
iv.setStyle(R.style.myotherstyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no
`setStyle()` method because you can't change the style after the view is
initialized.

---

Check this : 
[Where is the View.setStyle() method?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/88c53b8c790a750d)

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no way to change a style at runtime. Your best bet is to set the individual attributes (padding/margins/width/etc) one at a time at runtime.

Comment: or else if you got only 2 styles then make the imageView with these 2 styles and make 1 of them invisible at compile time and make it visible at runtime(the previous 1 is made invisible). any layout related thing is better done at compile time.